# several times insert area in smarty engine theme

Tags: php, themes, smarty, area

i want to insert area for several times in smarty theme engine v3.

for example in smarty theme :

```
{block name="menu"}
{$menu.title}
{/block}
```

output of theme :

```
menu1
menu2
menu3
```

php code :

```
$smarty->assign("menu",array('title' => 'menu1'));
$smarty->assign("menu",array('title' => 'menu2'));
$smarty->assign("menu",array('title' => 'menu3'));
```

but smarty always show last assign (menu3).
i don't want to use array loop for and foreach.
i do it in smarty v 2 but i can't do it in new version (3).

Comment: AFAIK, you can't assign different values to same variable without using arrays. Fix would be to use separate vars for menu1, menu2 and menu3

Comment: your php code seems to be overriding the menu var, so you were able to see only menu3 on display

Comment: so how to insert a block for several times ?

Comment: use an array or different variable names

Comment: i don't want to use array,in old smarty i can but new smarty can't?